# best way to calculate available slots in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects as below.

```
prepareTimeStamps = [
    {
        "date": "01/23",
        "name": "Jimmy",
        "startTime": "01/23/2022 5:00 pm",
        "endTime": "01/23/2022 7:00 pm",
        "slots": "05:00 PM,05:30 PM,06:00 PM,06:30 PM,07:00 PM"
    },
    {
        "date": "01/23",
        "name": "James",
        "startTime": "01/23/2022 5:00 pm",
        "endTime": "01/23/2022 6:00 pm",
        "slots": "05:00 PM,05:30 PM,06:00 PM"
    },
    {
        "date": "01/23",
        "name": "Jason", 
        "startTime": "01/23/2022 5:00 pm",
        "endTime": "01/23/2022 7:00 pm",
        "slots": "05:00 PM,05:30 PM,06:00 PM,06:30 PM,07:00 PM"
    }
]
```

Here James is available for 5 to 6 PM only however, Jimmy and Jason are available 5 to 7 PM. So I want results like 5 to 6 PM all 3 are available, but for 5 to 7 only 2 people are available.

I tried using calculating the string length of slots but it couldn't work for smaller strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! What is your question? Forming an actual question regarding the goal you are trying to achieve would help you.

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the sample input you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

One idea can be to calculate the hours between midnight the start/end of the slots. Then make the same calculation for request part and compare the numbers. The code down below should calculate, but I didn't run it. If it works, it will return

```
[9, 13.5]
// when the slots:
"09:00 PM,....01:30 AM"
```

```js
let slots = "05:00 PM,05:30 PM,06:00 PM,06:30 PM,07:00 PM"

let freeTime = slots.split(',').map(slot => freeTime(calculate(slot)));

let calculate = (slot) => {
  return slot.trim().split(' ').map(time => hoursFromMidnight(time));
}

let hoursFromMidnight = (time) => {
  let [h, m] = time[0].split(':');
  
  return  parsInt(h)
        + time[1].toLowerCase() == 'am' ? 12 : 0
        + parseInt(m) / 60;
}


const freeTime = (slots) => {
  return [slots[0], slots[slots.length - 1]]
}
```